# Join results of for into one string

Tags: swift, loops

I have places stored in core data in an entity called "Places" that has an attribute called "name". My current for loop to return each name works well, and the print in the console shows all of the names as expected. Currently, the console shows each one on a separate line, as they are from separate places. Is it possible to fetch all names from each place and store then in a single string. Here is the current code:

```
    do {
        let results = try myContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Places]

            for places in results{         
                let array = [places.name!].joinWithSeparator(", ")
                print(array)
            }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Here is the output, that is on each line (which shows they are separate objects), but i'd like them to be in one string (and printed on the same line with a comma separator)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoY63.png)

The output I would like printed is:
France, Germany, Poland, Hungary, Serbia

Thank you for reading, I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` method.

```
let placeNames = results.reduce("") { (placeNames, place) -> String in
    return placeNames + place.name + " "
}
```

Now you have a single `String` with the concatenation of all the place names.

### Short notation

You can also write it as follow

```
let placeNames = results.reduce("") { $0 + $1.name + " " }
```

### Example

Lets say `Place` is defined as follow (I am using a `Struct` however a `Class` does work as well)

```
struct Place {
    let name: String
}
```

Now let's define `results` as an array of `Place(s)`

```
let results = [Place(name: "Italy"), Place(name: "UK"), Place(name: "USA")]
```

And finally let's test the code

```
let placeNames = results.reduce("") { $0 + " " + $1.name }
print(placeNames) // "Italy UK USA "
```

### Removing the last blank space

You maybe have noticed that a blank space is appended at the and of the generated `String`. We can get rid of that updating the code as follow

```
let placeNames = String(
    places
        .reduce("") { $0 + $1.name + " " }
        .characters
        .dropLast()
)
```

### Why this solution is better then a for loop?

The code I am suggesting here does follow the **Functional Programming** paradigm. There are several advantages over the classic for loop:

1. It's thread safe: since I am only using immutable values you don't have to worry about other threads that could change your values while you are using them.
2. It's less error prone because it's more declarative: we are describing how the result should be, not how to build it.

That's it :)

Comment: Why not just use `joinWithSeparator`, so you don't have to worry about the last space?

Comment: @Eendje: I think this is a very good suggestion. I am adding it to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Eendje: Ops I did not notice you posted your own answer. I will remove the update from my answer then.

Comment: @appzYourLife: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! It is working now! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I originally tried to implement the joinWithSeperator as you can see with my original post, an option to see it working with this will also be appreciated!

Comment: @rscode101: take a look at the answer by `Eendje`. He did it with `joinWithSeparator`

Comment: Oh actually I posted my answer just to show he could fetch the results in one line. I don't mind if you edit your answer, since you explained everything in a much better explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the put the results right into one string you can do:

```
let results = (try? myContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [Places] ?? []
let places = results.flatMap { $0.name }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you use this, you won't have an error message. So only use this if you don't need the error message :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a loop: (the '$0' is the argument in the closure)

```
results.forEach{ print($0, terminator:" ") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to specify 2 things

## FRP

You can use function style on sequence types.
In this can you want to transform an array of `Places` in a array of `name` of the places.

To do that you can use the `map` function.

`places.map{$0.name}` will returns an array of name.

As name is optional, use `flatMap` instead that strip out `nil` values

`let string = places.flatMap{$0.name}.joinWithSeparator(", ")`

### Error throwing

You are using `as!` to cast. You won't be able to recover error if this fails.

You may want to add a security in your code, in a simple manner.

#### Throwing unwraping

You can declare a function that throws an error when unwrapping.

```
enum UnwrapError: ErrorType {
    case Failed
}

func unwrap<A>(optional: A?) throws -> A {
    guard let unwrap = optional else {
        throw UnwrapError.Failed
    }
    return unwrap
}


do {
    let results = try unwrap(myContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Places])
    print(places.flatMap{$0.name}.joinWithSeparator(", "))

} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Then you may want to unit test your `fetchRequest` to check that it returns `[Places]`